# Adding values per 4 rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I used "pandas.read_csv" and the data is shown below

```
　　　A　　　　　B　　　　　　C　　　　　　　D
00　　2019-2　　315993352　　7         　　78
01　　2019-1　　317515869　　3         　　69
02　　2018-4　　318533054　　4         　　66
03　　2018-3　　318769547　　5         　　65
04　　2018-2　　319952126　　6         　　69
05　　2018-1　　322476579　　None　　      70
06　　2017-4　　323018027　　5         　　63
07　　2017-3　　321828003　　4         　　58
08　　2017-2　　321337443　　3         　　52
09　　2017-1　　322300905　　4         　　46
10　　2016-4　　321747881　　3         　　45
11　　2016-3　　324384755　　2         　　44
12　　2016-2　　456366381　　5         　　50
13　　2016-1　　453014579　　3         　　70
14　　2015-4　　452271967　　4         　　115
15　　2015-3　　452000000　　2         　　59
16　　2015-2　　453243847　　None　　  　　59
17　　2015-1　　321738470　　1         　　62
```

it has 18 rows.
I want to add values of C columns per 4 rows and make new dataframe:
row0+row1+row2+row3(7+3+4+5)  row4+row5+row6+row7(6+0+5+4)  row8+row9+row10+row11(3+4+3+2)  row12+row13+row14+row15(5+3+4+2)

and 18 cannot be divided by 4
so I want to throw row16,row17

+)And The result that I want is

```
19
15
12
14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
N = 4

#first remove last rows if remainders
df = df.iloc[:len(df) // N * N]
#convert to numeric
df['C'] = pd.to_numeric(df['C'], errors='coerce')
#aggregate sum 
df = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // N)['C'].sum().to_frame()
print (df)
      C
0  19.0
1  15.0
2  12.0
3  14.0
```

For integers is possible replace missing or None values to `0`:

```
N = 4

df = df.iloc[:len(df) // N * N]

df['C'] = pd.to_numeric(df['C'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)

df = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // N)['C'].sum().to_frame()
print (df)
    C
0  19
1  15
2  12
3  14
```

Comment: and then new Error sign appears. ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'None'

Comment: I'm really sorry. I changed my example.